OData and ASP.NET Core : how do I handle OData queries with dots in the key strings?
I have an OData interface running in an IIS application. When I try to update an entry whose primary key contains a dot, the application returns a 404 error.
This is the format of the URL that's returning the issue:
https://localhost:44351/odata/Table('Name.With.Dots')

I would remove the dots, but they're present in other data tables that I need to compare with later. Is there a way to tell my website to not worry about this?
Bonus points if I can test this locally when I launch the application via IIS Express, where I do not appear to have a dedicated web.config file (or it has another name, or I can't find it - something is up).
It's worth mentioning that this update is occurring during a SaveChangesAsync on the OData context; this can potentially be fixed by adding a trailing slash to the URL, but alas, that's out of my control.
